# LocalStorage image load - strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want to load an image from local storage if it is saved there, otherwise the script should load image from file and save it to a local storage - if I open the site two times at row, the first site should be filled by the image from a file, the second one by the image from local storage.

What is interesting is the fact that it works in some cases (I change only local storage name - it's `lsItem` in the function), but in most of them it doesn't.
Look at the output of my console after loading has failed - I've made a few `console.log`'s in the code:

```
script.js:10 data:,
script.js:13 LocalStorage photo
data:image/jpg;base64,data:,:1 GET data:image/jpg;base64,data:, 0 ()
```

It seems like nothing was converted into Base64. Displaying the image from a file works well, but when it comes to display from local storage, it doesn't work in most cases.
The interesting part is the fact that if I change the local storage name a few times - in some cases 10, in other 20 everything works well.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>LocalStorage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="myPhoto" src="" />
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
window.onload = function() {
    getImage('photo', 'myPhoto', 'img/kokos2.jpg');
}


function getImage(lsItem, elementId, imgSrc) {
    var localImage = localStorage.getItem(lsItem);
    imgObject = document.getElementById(elementId);
    console.log(localImage);
    if (localImage !== null) {
        imgObject.src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + localImage;
        console.log("LocalStorage photo");
    } else {
        imgObject.src = imgSrc;
        imgData = getBase64Image(imgObject);
        localStorage.setItem(lsItem, imgData);
        console.log("Photo from file");
    }
}

function getBase64Image(img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");

    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

EDIT
I had to change the else statement -

```
 else {
        imgObject.src = imgSrc;
        imgObject.onload = function() {
            imgData = getBase64Image(imgObject);
            localStorage.setItem(lsItem, imgData);
        }
        console.log("Photo from file");
    }
```

Comment: Did you try setting an `onload` listener to the image in the `else` statement, calling `getBase64Image` only after the image was actually painted?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado it works as I expected, thank you!

Comment: No worries. But please don't edit the question to write the answer: it becomes a mess. Just write yourself the answer in the *answer* space (provided this is not a duplicate).